# Trying to get a website to zoom 120% when screen resolution is greater than 1600px

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm working on an website, and someone asked me if it was possible to zoom the entire website when someone has a screen width of 1600px or greater.

Now I've tried something with css3 and media queries, and I've read a lot on the internet, but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the media query I've created in the CSS.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1600px) {
* {
    zoom: 500%;
}
```

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Don't use it..

Use a media query like you have and adjust elements individually!

Comment: @JayMoy This site is way too big to style every element again, so that's not possible. This project i'm working on also is almost 10 years old.

Comment: That would zoom every element by 500%, wouldn't it be sufficient with applying the zoom just to the body tag?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Yes, that would be sufficient, changed that now. And the 500% is just so I could see the effect of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  body {
    /* webkit browsers */
    zoom: 120%;
    /* moz browsers , since there is no support to "zoom" */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0
  }
}
```

here is a snippet:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  body {
    /* webkit browsers */
    zoom: 120%;
    /* moz browsers , since there is no support to "zoom" */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div>this is going to be BIG when width is minimum 1600px</div>
```